# Jboss Auto start

Tags: java, jboss, autostart

I have Jboss 5 installed/configured.  I would like the ability to have Jboss auto start when my VM boots up.  I see in my Jboss bin directory I have a startup script jboss_init_redhat.sh

I am assuming I have to get that script into my /etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss file

Then I am stuck, what is my next step?

Thank you for helping a beginner

Comment: Jared - can you not edit (if needed) and copy the jboss_init_redhat.sh file in yourself?  Is your VM redhat?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your response.  Yes, I guess I have to copy the script into the /etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss file.....?? Yes my VM is RHEL.  I am just not sure what to do after I do copy that script.. or do I have anything else to do? 

Sorry I am trying to teach myself this on the fly...

Answer (score 5):

According to [How do I Start JBoss on boot with Linux?](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/StartJBossOnBootWithLinux) on JBoss Community Wiki, your task is to:

> - create a user for JBoss (recommended) so that JBoss can be
>     restricted to accessing only the files
>     and system resources that it has
>     permission to access via the "jboss"
>     user.
> - create a script called /etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss
> - create a link called /etc/rc3.d/S84jboss
>
>   - optionally /etc/rc5.d/S84jboss and /etc/rc4.d/S84jboss
> - create a link called /etc/rc6.d/K15jboss
>
>   - create the K15
>       link in /etc/rc1.d, /etc/rc2.d,
>       /etc/rc0.d

For the 2nd step, you can indeed use the `jboss_init_redhat.sh` file that ships with JBoss. For more information, check the link given above, it details each step.

Comment: Thank you.  When they say "create a link called /etc/rc3.d/S84jboss" does that mean I have to first create a file S84jboss THEN create the link?

Comment: No, `/etc/rc3.d/S84jboss` is the name of the link. Actually, `cd` into /etc/rc3.d and type `ln -s ../init.d/jboss S84jboss`

Answer (score -1):

The stock init script is very primitive; here's my take at a better one: https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBPAPP-3194